# Dimension of isotropy group in homogenous space

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Just sincerely ask a fundamental problem as the following:

We know

1. $G = GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a transitive group of dimension $4$.
2. The vector space $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acting on is $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, which is **homogenous space**.
3. Since $G$ is a transitive group, $X$ is isomorphic to $G/G_x$, where $G_x$ is an isotropy group.    So $\dim G/G_x=\dim X = 2$
4. $\dim  G/G_x = \dim G-\dim G_x\Rightarrow 2 = 4-\dim G_x$.
5. So I get $\dim G_x = 2$.

Am I correct? Or is there any step wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The usual action of $GL(2,\Bbb{R})$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$ is not transitive, since $0$ is in its own orbit. It is transitive on $\Bbb{R}^2\setminus 0$.

Comment: Other than Dietrich's comment, everything else looks fine.